# Connection timeout after adding new IP on CentOS

Tags: linux-networking

After I added new IP according to guide from my provider: http://help.ovh.com/IpAlias i started having trouble with connection.

While ping is always OK some ports don't work. I loose connection to the VPS randomly, i can work connected to SSH on my custom port and then suddenly no connection. I have to switch to my "failover" ip to continue my work. Yes. Second ip on eth0:0 works just fine all the time. Apache, SSH... no problems.

So here my net cfg:

```
  [root@vps network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
IPV6INIT="yes"
MTU="1500"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="xx"

[root@vps network-scripts]# cat ifcfg-eth0:0
DEVICE="eth0:0"
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR="51.2XX.1XX.2XX"
NETMASK="255.255.255.255"
ONBOOT="yes"
BROADCAST="51.2XX.1XX.2XX"
```

I've tried disabling firewall (csf, lfd) but it didn't help, and i don't even know why it would, i haven't change any single thing except adding failover ip. It was just fine, now every few minutes i lose connection. The most annoying thing is that FailoverIP works while main ip does not.

Comment: Check your system logs.

Comment: I checked messages what else can i check?

Comment: I would connect via your "failover" IP, since you said it was always stable, run `tcpdump` from that session.  Monitor traffic on eth0 and filter out the IP address with the problem.  Then ssh to the problem IP and see what tcpdump reports.  You might have to bring the problem to your hosting provider.